# clicking Android Studio shows up IntelliJ

Tags: android-studio

> I am trying to open **android studio** but **intellij** is shown instead, i have searched for answers but they are irrelevant, what to do?

Comment: Let it open the intellij and in the settings->Plugin search if you have disabled android  plugin. enable it and restart again.

Comment: thanks for the help @Jay, but in the end i have to reinstall the IDE since my laptop is acting up again.